# pow function c++ error

Tags: c++, pow

I am trying to create a helper function for a decimal to binary converter which will tell me which bit to start at based on the highest power of 2.

This is the code I have:

```
int determineStart(int val){
   int topval = 1;
   int i = 0;
   for(i = 0; val > 2 * topval; ++i){
      topval = pow(2, i);
   }
   return topval;
}
```

I get the following error: 
`main.cpp:9: error: call of overloaded pow(int, int&) is ambiguous`

I've tried switching several things around (such as putting in a `double` or a separate variable as the second param for `pow()`, making `topval` a `double`, etc) but couldn't seem to get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there Other `pow` definitions in the program? Please post the complete program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest (and fastest) way to get powers of two is shifting - the CPU is using binary anyway, so it can just add a few extra zeroes on the end for you.

So instead of `pow(2, i)` you would write `(1 << i)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `pow()` function for such argument types. It can be `(float, int)`, `(double, int)` or `(long double, int)`. If you call it with `(int, int)` the compiler doesn't know which of above types use. The simplest solution would be to do:

```
pow(2.0, i)
```

EDIT :
I assume you use standard `pow()` definition from `<cmath>` or `<math.h>`

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010 and I get error: ambiguous call to overloaded function.

Comment: @ShikharBhardwaj More overloads were added in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Casting is probably your error: you can easily cast int to double or float. 
try this:

```
pow(2.0, i)
```

it will behave like:

```
pow((double)(2), i)
```